# Using fdisk -r to read disk in Solaris

Tags: shell, solaris

Upon reading the fdisk's man page on Solaris, I came across the -r flag:

```
 -r 
  Read from disk and write to stdout. See -o and -s, which 
  specify the starting point and size of operation.
```

Using fdisk -r outputs a help page only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do fdisk -r you need to be root and supply a raw disk device such as /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0.
Then you need to tell it the offset block with -o option and the number of blocks with -s option.

try:

```
$ fdisk -r -o 20 -s 20 /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0 > {some other disk directory file}
```